# My USB camera is no longer recognised as a storage device

Tags: usb, mount, udev, camera

When I plug the USB cable into my Nikon camera, it used to be recognised as a storage device, /dev/sdc or so, of which a slice could then be mounted with

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

This no longer works: the camera is still recognised, witness dmesg, but it doesn't show up as a storage device. I suppose I need to create a udev rule but have no idea how to begin.

```
[2942828.789770] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[2942828.923041] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=022e
[2942828.923049] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2942828.923053] usb 1-4: Product: NIKON DSC COOLPIX P610
```

[2942828.923057] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: NIKON

Comment: I ought to have checked this before: the camera does NOT show up in lsusb output.